# Switch statement for matching substrings of a String

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, switch-statement

Im trying to ask for some values from a variable.
The variable is going to have the description of the weather and I want to ask for specific words in order to show different images (like sun, rain or so).
I have code like this:

```
if self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("clear") != nil {
    self.imageWeather.image = self.soleadoImage
}
if self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("rain") != nil {
    self.imageWeather.image = self.soleadoImage
}
if self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("broken clouds") != nil {
    self.imageWeather.image = self.nubladoImage
}
```

When I tried to add an "OR" condition, Xcode gives me some weird errors.

Is it possible to do a `switch` sentence with that? Or anyone knows how to do add an OR condition to the `if` clause?

Comment: How did you add an "OR" condition and what weird error did you get?

Comment: For example if i want to put the first and the second one in the same if sentence:          if self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("Clear") != nil | self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("broken clouds") != nil
       {
        self.imageWeather.image = self.soleadoImage
       } and the errors are: Non-associative operator is adjacent to operator of same precedence  and Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '($T17, NilLiteralConvertible)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift language has two kinds of `OR` operators - the bitwise ones `|` (single vertical line), and the logical ones `||` (double vertical line). In this situation you need a logical `OR`:

```
if self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("Clear") != nil || self.descriptionWeather.description.rangeOfString("clear") != nil {
    self.imageWeather.image = self.soleadoImage
}
```

Unlike Objective-C where you could get away with a bitwise `OR` in exchange for getting a slightly different run-time semantic, Swift requires a logical `OR` in the expression above.

Answer (score 103):

I had a similar problem today and realized this question hasn't been updated since Swift 1! Here's how I solved it in Swift 4:

```
switch self.descriptionWeather.description {
case let str where str.contains("Clear"):
    print("clear")
case let str where str.contains("rain"):
    print("rain")
case let str where str.contains("broken clouds"):
    print("broken clouds")
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: This solution/answer is much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 25):

### Swift 5 Solution

```
func weatherImage(for identifier: String) -> UIImage? {
    switch identifier {
    case _ where identifier.contains("Clear"),
         _ where identifier.contains("rain"):
        return self.soleadoImage
    case _ where identifier.contains("broken clouds"):
        return self.nubladoImage
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with a switch statement using value binding and a `where` clause. But convert the string to lowercase first!

```
var desc = "Going to be clear and bright tomorrow"

switch desc.lowercaseString as NSString {
case let x where x.rangeOfString("clear").length != 0:
    println("clear")
case let x where x.rangeOfString("cloudy").length != 0:
    println("cloudy")
default:
    println("no match")
}

// prints "clear"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do this a lot, you can implement a custom `~=` operator that defines sub-string matching. It lends itself to this nice syntax:

```
switch "abcdefghi".substrings {
    case "def": // calls `"def" ~= "abcdefghi".substrings`
        print("Found substring: def") 
    case "some other potential substring":
        print("Found \"some other potential substring\"")
    default: print("No substring matches found")
}
```

Implementation:

```
import Foundation

public struct SubstringMatchSource {
    private let wrapped: String
    
    public init(wrapping wrapped: String) {
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    }
    
    public func contains(_ substring: String) -> Bool {
        return self.wrapped.contains(substring)
    }
    
    public static func ~= (substring: String, source: SubstringMatchSource) -> Bool {
        return source.contains(substring)
    }
}

extension String {
    var substrings: SubstringMatchSource {
        return SubstringMatchSource(wrapping: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking of something similar :) Good idea to wrap the string into a custom type. Perhaps define for StringProtocol instead of String?

Comment: @MartinR I tried, but I don't think contains is available on StringProtocol, and I was having some other generics error. Could you give it a shot?

Comment: ... which compiles in Swift 5, but not in Swift 4.

Comment: @MartinR if you constrain the struct generic type Index to String.Index `public struct SubstringMatchSource<S: StringProtocol> where S.Index == String.Index {` and `extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {` it does compile in Swift 4

Comment: @LeoDabus How restrictive is that constraint? What non-String types fit? Substring?

Comment: @LeoDabus: Indeed that's it. – Those restrictions have been added to the stdlib in Swift 5. I remember that it has been discussed in the Swift forum some time ago, but cannot find it right know. If I remember correctly, *all* StringProtocol conforming types should satisfy that restriction, and not requiring it in the stdlib was considered an omission (which has been fixed for Swift 5).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a dictionary instead, as a mapping between the substring you're searching for and the corresponding image:

```swift
func image(for weatherString: String) -> UIImage? {
    let imageMapping = [
        "Clear": self.soleadoImage,
        "rain": self.soleadoImage,
        "broken clouds": self.nubladoImage]
    return imageMapping.first { weatherString.contains($0.key) }?.value
}
```

A dictionary gives you flexibility, adding new mappings is easy to do.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://www.vperi.com/archives/284) also describes overloading operator ~= which is actually used by the switch statement for matching cases to allow you to match regular expressions.

Comment: Cool story, but link's dead