# How to use Swift literal regex expressions in switch case pattern statements?

Tags: swift, regex, switch-statement, swift5.7

How to use Swift literal regex expressions in switch case pattern statements?

Based on the examples from WWDC 2022 presention slides, the following is expected to compile and run OK:

```swift
import Foundation
import RegexBuilder

switch "abc" {
    case /\w+/:
        print("matched!")
    default:
        print("not matched.")
}
```

However, the following error is produced:

> Expression pattern of type `Regex<Substring>` cannot match values of type `String`

Can the `switch` `case` statement with a Swift regex literal expression be somehow modified to function OK? How would one use the new Swift 5.7 regex capabilties in the switch case pattern statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I have found, the "matching with regexes in `switch` statement" feature has not been implemented, because people were arguing about what the exact semantic should be. In case such as

```
switch "---abc---" {
case /\w+/:
    print("foo")
default:
    print("bar")
}
```

which branch should the switch statement run? Should it count as a match only if the whole string matches the regex, or is it enough only for a substring of the switched string to match? In other words, is it `wholeMatch` or `firstMatch`? See more of the discussion [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0357-regex-string-processing-algorithms/57225).

In the end, they were not able to come to a conclusion, and

> The proposal has been accepted with modifications (the modification being to subset out `~=` for now).

So the `~=` operator was not added for `Regex<Output>`, so you cannot use it in a switch.

You can add it yourself if you want, if you can decide between the two semantics :) For example:

```
func ~=(regex: Regex<Substring>, str: String) -> Bool {
    // errors count as "not match"
    (try? regex.wholeMatch(in: str)) != nil
}
```

Comment: Through the years, I developed the "normally I'd use a regex like `/^…$/` to match the full string" coding habit. So, `firstMatch` works very well with the patterns I have. Easy choice. Thanks.

Comment: I am keeping your answer as accepted because it provided _timely, correct and critical information_. However, I ended up _not using_ the **`~=` approach** since Swift will likely define `~=` in the future. I later figued out an alternate solution that appears to be a future-proof, expressive, and readable. (See my posted answer for details)

Comment: Note that defining your own `~=` will not create errors down the road, because overload resolution favors operations defined outside the standard library over those defined in the standard library. It could result in _confusion_ for developers reading your source, however.

Comment: You can replace the global `~=` with one on your own custom wrapper type. See [this really similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54487077/3141234), where I add a `.substrings` field which returns a `SubstringMatchSource`, which has an `~=` operator which matches strings by their prefix. You can do similar similar for partial/whole matches of regexes.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the switch case statement with a Swift regex literal expression be somehow modified to function OK?

Yes, a **`case let … where …` pattern** with a **`/regex/` literal** can be used. This approach can also be implemented in a way that expressly avoids potential `~=` future ambiguities relative to the standard library. This approach is an alternative to directly defining `~=`.

> *Note that defining your own ~= will not create errors down the road, because overload resolution favors operations defined outside the standard library over those defined in the standard library. It could result in confusion for developers reading your source, however.* - Stephen Canon comment -

#### Discussion…

**Match-Part-Or-Whole Example** - A fundamental approach where the original regex pattern `/^…$/` is used to match a entire line:

```swift
extension String {
    func matchFirst(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool {
        // errors count as "not match"
        (try? regex.firstMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }
}

switch "---abc---" {
    case let s where s.matchFirst(/^\w+$/):
        print("entire line contains alphanumerics: '\(s)'")
    case let s where s.matchFirst(/\w+/):
        print("alphanumerics found in string: '\(s)'")
    default:
        print("no alphanumerics found")
}
```

**Whole-Match-Only Example** - A "whole match only" regex approach where a partial match is not possible:

```swift
extension String {
    func matchWhole(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool {
        // errors count as "not match"
        (try? regex.wholeMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }
}

switch "---abc---" {
    case let s where s.matchWhole(/\w+/):
        print("all alphanumerics: '\(s)'")
    //case partial match not available. whole or nothing.
    default:
        print("no match for /\\w+/")
}
```

I ended up using the "classic" **Match-Part-Or-Whole Example** approach instead of the **Whole-Match-Only Example** and **`func ~=`** approaches for the following reasons:

- **`func ~=`** - could possibly be defined by Swift at some future time. *Possible future confusion.*
- **Whole-Match-Only Example** - does not support both partial and full matches. *Less expressive.*
- **Match-Part-Or-Whole Example**

  - leaves `~=` undefined which allows for the possible future definition by Swift. *Avoids possible future confusion.*
  - does support both partial and full matches. *More expressive.*
  - `^…$` is expressly stated for a full line match. *More readable.*

---

Note: Extending `String` with *both convenience wrappers*, such as `matchFirst` and `matchWhole`, can allow for either approach to be choosen at the point of use. This approach provides the following benefits:

- *expressive*
- co-locates both choices in the *point-of-use* autocompletion list
- *avoids the conflict* of one vs the other in the lower level extension
- *does not presume any interpretation* for the not-yet-officially-defined `~=`.

```swift
extension String {
    func matchFirst(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool {
        // errors count as "not match"
        (try? regex.firstMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }

    func matchWhole(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool {
        // errors count as "not match"
        (try? regex.wholeMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }
}
```

---

**Historic Footnote**

The `^` begin-anchor and `$` end-anchor syntax has been part of Regular Expressions since the 1970s with `qed` and `ed` PDP-7 AT&T Bell Labs Unix editors.

*QED Text Editor* (1970 Bell Telephone Laboratories technical memorandum)

[image]

*ed* (see `man ed` or `info ed` on POSIX and Open Group compliant Unix-like systems)

[image]

See also `man ed` and `info ed` on modern BSD/Linux/Unix systems. It's still there.

The `^` begin-anchor and `$` end-anchor syntax was also carried forward to other Regular Expression enabled software tools, such as `sed`, `g/re/p` global regular expression, [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), and [POSIX standard Basic Regular Syntax (BRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

***If `/^.$/` pattern is implied and hidden for some compact code convenience then the REGEX expressive capability is reduced.***

Seeing, reading, and writing with *`^` begin-anchor* and *`$` end-anchor* syntax can be natural (and even expected) for an experienced REGEX user.